# Is it possible to work on a project from another computer through GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a project in Angular and I want to work on it on several computers simultaneously.

Do I need to open a virtual machine and copy the project files from there and then work from there,
Or it is possible through GitHub to pull the files and work on them in sync with GitHub on any computer I connect to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Git with a central remote is a very common way of working on the same thing from multiple computers. That is why Git is used for collaboration. In your example you are simply collaborating with yourself.